# In array of objects sum up certain property values if another property has given value

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I'm trying to get the sum of account balances if the account type is "Savings". My thought process was that to loop through the array using a forEach and then if the account type is savings, but not sure why it's not working.

```
const accounts = [
    {acctNo: 123, type: 'Checking', balance: 150},
    {acctNo: 234, type: 'Checking', balance: 200},
    {acctNo: 345, type: 'Savings', balance: 550},
    {acctNo: 456, type: 'Checking', balance: 550},
    {acctNo: 567, type: 'Savings', balance: 1500}
];
const sum = accounts.forEach(function(account){
  if (account.type=== 'Savings'){
    account.reduce(function(a,b){
      return {balance: a.balance + b.balance}
    })
  }
})

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: there are a number of problems with your code - but most fundamentally, you're overcomplicating it. You just need to `filter` into the accounts with type `Savings`, `map` those to their balance, and only then perform the sum (with either `reduce` or a sum with `forEach`, whichever you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't return anything in a forEach, and reducing directly on accounts doesn't make sense. Try filter and map instead, and make sure you do reduce on a list:

```
accounts.filter(a => a.type === 'Savings')
    .map(a => a.balance)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

Comment: You may [filter and add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61761959/11299053) along a single pass over the source array

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this, by chaining some simple array methods:

1) use `filter` to get only the accounts with type `'Savings'`

2) use `map` to get only the balances

3) then sum the array, which I've done using `reduce` which sits nicely alongside `map` and `filter`, but which you could have done using an explicit loop and keeping manual track of the sum, if you prefer

Note that I've used arrow functions, just because it's a bit more concise and makes it clearer (imo) what the functions are doing - but each could be replaced with an old-style `function() { ... }` expression and it would still work the same.

```js
const accounts = [
    {acctNo: 123, type: 'Checking', balance: 150},
    {acctNo: 234, type: 'Checking', balance: 200},
    {acctNo: 345, type: 'Savings', balance: 550},
    {acctNo: 456, type: 'Checking', balance: 550},
    {acctNo: 567, type: 'Savings', balance: 1500}
];

const sum = accounts.filter(account => account.type === 'Savings')
                    .map(account => account.balance)
                    .reduce((acc, bal) => acc + bal);

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply do that [in 1 pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61761959/11299053)?

Comment: fair point - your answer is neat and probably more performant (although I wouldn't be confident saying that without actual benchmarks on large datasets, modern JS engines are capable of optimisations that I wouldn't even begin to understand), but most often that won't matter. I just wanted to demonstrate to the OP the simple way to do it, since they were clearly confused about what was going on with the various array methods, so I find the "step by step" sort of thinking shown by my answer to be helpful.

Comment: *'...probably more performant'* You [will see](https://jsbench.me/18ka4f49yq/1) around 40% performance gain for 1k random records.

Comment: fair point (I only fudged because I wasn't sure and was too lazy to benchmark myself :) ) - but still, when the "bad" performance version can deal with an array of 1k records at 1/3000 of a second, this isn't going to be an actually noticeable performance difference until you have hundreds of thousands. You're right to raise this, and I thank you for doing so - but for most practical uses it's irrelevant.

Comment: Zygmond : The point of my initial comment was not to highlight performance gap, though for some applications where you may do multiple heavy calculations like that even few milliseconds gained on render stage may matter. However, I rather wanted to show the way of solving the issue in a truly *lazy* way ;)

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` is an array method, not an object method.

You don't need to use both `forEach` and `reduce`. `reduce` already iterates over the array, you just need to put the `if` condition into the function.

```js
const accounts = [
    {acctNo: 123, type: 'Checking', balance: 150},
    {acctNo: 234, type: 'Checking', balance: 200},
    {acctNo: 345, type: 'Savings', balance: 550},
    {acctNo: 456, type: 'Checking', balance: 550},
    {acctNo: 567, type: 'Savings', balance: 1500}
];
const sum = accounts.reduce(function(a, account){
  if (account.type === 'Savings'){
    return a + account.balance;
  } else {
    return a;
  }
}, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @RobinZigmond's comment

`filter` => removes all accounts from the array that are not of type 'Savings' and returns those of `type === 'savings'` as an array. The `map` method receives this array

`map` => returns an array of only the balance of the savings accounts. `reduce` receives it

`reduce` => basically reduces everything in an array to one thing. In this case, it receives the array of the balances and adds them all up and returns it to `sum`

```
const accounts = [
  { acctNo: 123, type: 'Checking', balance: 150 },
  { acctNo: 234, type: 'Checking', balance: 200 },
  { acctNo: 345, type: 'Savings', balance: 550 },
  { acctNo: 456, type: 'Checking', balance: 550 },
  { acctNo: 567, type: 'Savings', balance: 1500 }
];

const sum = accounts
  .filter((account) => account.type.toLowerCase() === 'savings')
  .map((savingsAccounts) => savingsAccounts.balance)
  .reduce((accumulator, balance) => accumulator + balance);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: There's no point in doing 3 passes over the source array, and its filtered copy, whereas 1 is [absolutely enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61761959/11299053)